# JdbcTemplate and stored procedure from package Oracle12cDialect

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I`m trying to call stored procedure "getGlobalParamValue" from package APP Oracle10g

org.springframework.boot version '2.2.0.RELEASE'

```
FUNCTION getGlobalParamValue(
        pCode VARCHAR2  
    RETURN INTEGER;
```

When I run it in SQL developer, everything is ok I get right result

I`ve tryed

1.

```
    jdbcTemplate.update("BEGIN APP.getGlobalParamValue('base'); END;");
```

or
2.

```
    val sjc = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                        .withCatalogName("APP")
                        .withProcedureName("getGlobalParamValue");
    sjc.useInParameterNames("pCode")
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                    .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("p_out", OracleTypes.INTEGER),
                     new SqlParameter("pCode", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("pCode", "base");
    sjc.execute(in);
```

it does not work

I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550`
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to get primitive type as result

```
val sql = "select APP.getGlobalParamValue('baseAirport') from dual";
val seq = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {}, Long.class);
```

I found an example It`s interesting
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/stored-procedures-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Using JdbcTemplate:**

```
 int returnResult = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT APP.getGlobalParamValue(?) FROM DUAL", new Object[] {pCode});
```

**Using EntityManager:**

```
    BigDecimal returnResult = null;

    returnResult = (BigDecimal) entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                    "SELECT APP.getGlobalParamValue(:pCode) FROM DUAL" )
            .setParameter("pCode", yourPCode)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to get dataset as result

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from table(MYPACKAGE.getrows(21861, 6793, 1829,57464))",(ResultSet rs)->{
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt("ID"));
    }
});
```